# How do I unlock the yellow gun?

Tags: antichamber

I know the green gun can be used to solve wall puzzles, which cause cycling loops of blocks, but I cannot get past the yellow wall to reach the yellow gun. Can anyone help?

[image])

Answer (score 5):

First, you need to have the green gun to get the yellow gun. The yellow gun can be found by going through the room called "Lighting the Fuse". The following path will take you to that room (you should start by teleporting to the farthest down on the list):

- Leap of Faith (the starting room, I think): jump off and land on the ledge before the bottom
- A Jump Too Far: walk across the gap without jumping
- Three Paths In Sight: walk backwards through the door to the right
- Window Of Opportunity: go through the green window
- Too Many Lasers: block off the laser grid with green blocks
- Lighting the Fuse: go through the doors

Comment: See also [How do I solve 'Lighting the Fuse' to get the yellow gun?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/103460)

Answer (score 2):

There is a second way to unlock the yellow gun.  From **Three Paths** *(which you should have found already, hit ESC and find it on the map)*

- **Three Paths:**  Walk to the **left**.  Stare at the wall with the eye on it until it disappears.
- **Running into Trouble:** Walk across the path *(hold shift)*
- **Ground Floor**: Go straight.  Block off the second laser with the blocks.
- **Managing Resources**: Duplicate the blocks *(Make a 3x3 square with a hole in the center)* so you have enough blocks to go right.
- **Link in a Chain Reaction**: You need to create a chain that has approximately the same length to every endpoint.  Something like this will work *(hover over to see spoiler)*:

> [image: Link in a Chain Reaction solution]
>  Then remove the block where they all connect (Not the one I'm aiming at)
>  *(I have the yellow gun already in this screenshot, but it is obviously not required)*

Answer (score 0):

I also found a third way to unlock the yellow gun, but it might be a glitch.

- Start out in **Connecting the Pieces**, and grab a bunch of blocks

  [image: Connecting the pieces]
- Turn around, jump down to **Stairway to Heaven** and take the elevator down to **The Butterfly Effect**.
- Here's the possible glitch:

  > Shoot the cubes over the walls before entering the anti-cube field, then grab them again from the other end.
  >
  >  [image: The Butterfly Effect glitch]
- Build a staircase up the hole in the ceiling to reach **A Link To The Past**.  Open the door to unlock the yellow gun. There is a sign here implying that you shouldn't be able to go this way until *after* you get the yellow gun :)

Comment: I don't think it's a glitch, in fact I've tested all other chambers like that, and that was the only one which let you shoot blocks at the ceiling.