# How do I solve 'Lighting the Fuse' to get the yellow gun?

Tags: antichamber

To access the yellow gun, there are many locked doors in a transparent tunnel, and the switches to unlock the doors are outside the tunnels. If I activate a switch to unlock one door, I don't have enough time to block the door before it closes.

[image: Yellow gun and doors blocked]

How can I build a timer to get enough time to block the doors? Is there a time machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to block the doors: make a "fuse" with blocks and "light" it up.  Then move through the doors as they open and close one by one.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow gun can also be accessed through a different path without solving this puzzle. When you have the yellow gun, this puzzle becomes a lot easier.

Comment: Wait, really?  Where/how?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I don't remember, to be honest. But the only way I was able to solve the "Lighting the fuse" puzzle was using the cube-moving functionality of the yellow gun. I never realized that you can solve it with the green gun by connecting the cubes before reading the answer by bartitan.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't even find this way into the yellow gun chamber until after I'd found the red gun...

Comment: I found the second path; it's [thru **'Link in a Chain Reaction'**](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/103981/2578)