# What does the green gun do in AntiChamber?

Tags: antichamber

**What special ability does the Green Gun have?** I'm trying to solve the puzzle in Deja Vu with the spring mechanism found in Butterfly effect (don't give me the solution please, just tell me what the gun does.

Answer (score 5):

The green gun serves two purposes:

- It can place lines of cubes via a thin beam - you can use it to place cubes in otherwise blocked off areas (thin "slots" on walls). It's as simple as pressing and holding the left mouse button.
- It can be used to quickly delete existing cubes - like the blue gun, only faster. While on the surface it may seem like just being able to do what you already could do faster isn't much of an improvement there are a few moments where this comes in handy.
- In a line of cubes, deleting a cube NOT on either end will cause the smaller section to vanish. If done in the middle, then all the cubes will vanish. *(Also, it's what murgatroid99 wrote, to give credit where credit's due!)*
- Placing cubes in a closed loop (a minimum of 8 cubes forming a 3x3 square empty in the middle), will cause it to be filled in the middle. This can be used to create more cubes when you're missing some.

Comment: All cubes have these properties, not just green ones.

Comment: Incorrect! I just checked, and blue cubes (as placed with the blue gun) will NOT grow when a closed loop is created, NOR will they vanish if you "cut off" the shorter part of a line!

Comment: @Shaamaan — I just tested myself, and found that blue cubes are capable of both short-end deletion (there's a [line of blue blocks](http://i.imgur.com/nTAZSrE.jpg) on the other side of a wall behind you at Taking Baby Steps) and filling (bring some extra blocks with you to [Managing Resources](http://i.imgur.com/OR3FjOg.jpg)).  Both are a function of the gun color, not the block color.

Comment: You have a red gun in your screenshot! Meaning, when you pick those blocks up, you will **turn them into RED cubes**, and they will gain properties of red cubes. Blue cubes alone (that is, cubes placed with the blue gun) will NOT have these properties. Note [this image](http://imgur.com/Lht3xgx). If the blue cubes had properties of green / red cubes, the the left side would vanish.

Comment: @Shaamaan — That's exactly my point — they're features of the **gun**, not the cubes.  Cube color doesn't influence behavior, only gun color.

Comment: I decided to do another test. I picked the yellow gun and used it's command ability (which doesn't change colours) to form a loop using blue cubes found in Taking Baby Steps. Indeed, in this case, the loop closed. I couldn't test deletion this way, obviously. As such, I must admit were correct. I am a bit disappointed however - if we got a gun which didn't change cube colours we could make for some interesting puzzles if cube colour determined the properties... I also wonder how the game prevents these mechanics when using the blue gun.

Answer (score 2):

The green gun can create lines (possibly bending) of blocks by holding the left mouse button. These lines can act as fuses: when you divide a line of blocks into two lines by removing a block, the shorter line (or possibly both) will start disappearing from the point of the removed block. You can use this to remove a block far away at a time delay.

Comment: The "fuse" mechanism is a spoiler.

Comment: Thanks :) I was trying to work out why blocks were sometimes disappearing.

Comment: @wok I'm pretty sure the fuse mechanism is demonstrated in the room where you get the green gun. Maybe not the exact mechanics of it, but showing that removing a block makes adjacent blocks disappear

Comment: I see your point. However, I only thought of using this property to create a fuse [in the room adjacent to the yellow gun](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/103460/3921).

Comment: I just got the green gun and progressed a few more rooms beyond, and I never noticed the fuse effect nor saw anything (looking back) that would demonstrate it. The only difference I found was the ability to hold right- and left-mouse to remove and place blocks quickly.